# jQuery slideToggle() not working on div with display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a responsive menu for which I'm using slidetoggle. There is an a element I click to trigger a slideToggle on the .menu element. The html and css for that element look like this:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation clearfix" role="navigation">
            <a href="#" id="responsive-menu" class="visible-xs active"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>

            <div class="menu">
                       <ul>
                           <li class="page_item page-item-9"><a href="http://dev.monkeyapps.nl/contact/">Contact</a></li>
                           <li class="page_item page-item-5"><a href="http://dev.monkeyapps.nl/features/">Features</a></li>
                           <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://dev.monkeyapps.nl/voorbeeld-pagina/">Over MonkeyApps</a></li>
                           <li class="page_item page-item-7"><a href="http://dev.monkeyapps.nl/prijzen/">Prijzen</a></li>
                      </ul>
            </div>

</nav>
```

All CSS associated with these elements:

```
.main-navigation {
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 0 25px;    
}

.main-navigation a#responsive-menu {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 32px;
    float: right;
}

.main-navigation a#responsive-menu:hover,
.main-navigation a#responsive-menu:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main-navigation a#responsive-menu i {
    display: none;
}

    .main-navigation a#responsive-menu i:first-child {
        display: inline;
    }

    .main-navigation a#responsive-menu.active i:first-child {
        display: none;
    }

    .main-navigation a#responsive-menu.active i {
        display: inline;
    }

.menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-navigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    .main-navigation ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 45px;
        line-height: 45px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #0091ea;
    }

        .main-navigation ul li a {
            display: inline-block;
            font-family: 'Alright_bold';
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #fff;
            width: 100%;
            height: 45px;
            line-height: 45px;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 3px;
        }

        .main-navigation ul li a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .main-navigation ul li a:before {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 3px;
            width: 0;
            transition: width 0s ease, background .5s ease;
        }

        .main-navigation ul li a:after {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 3px;
            width: 0;
            background: #fff;
            transition: width .5s ease;
        }

        .main-navigation ul li a:hover:before {
            width: 100%;
            background: #fff;
            transition: width .5s ease;
        }

        .main-navigation ul li a:hover:after {
            width: 100%;
            background: transparent;
            transition: all 0s ease;
        }
```

As you see there is one wrapper for the menu and the button that triggers the mobile menu. The bit of jquery which includes slideToggle:

```
$('#responsive-menu').click(
     function () {
       $(".menu").slideToggle();
       $("#responsive-menu").toggleClass("active");
     }
);
```

The thing with this is that the slideToggle is in fact triggered and there is stuff happening. Also there are no errors whatsoever. The menu isn't being made visible though and I really can't figure out why, does anyone know how to solve this?

A JSFiddle for the problem:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ph46ecz/)

Comment: Please provide a JsFiddle for your problem

Comment: Works fine for me -> **http://jsfiddle.net/49fakhd3/**

Comment: @aardnoot, in jsfiddle at the left panel there is jquery version, change it to 2.1.3 and it works fine

Comment: your jsFiddle uses **jQuery 3.0.0-alpha1**. change it to any of the stable releases e.g. **jQuery 2.1.3**.

Comment: In this case the problem is not the jQuery version used, but where the  rule `display: none;` is placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually you are using `jquery alpha`

use this jquery:
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


 $('#responsive-menu').click(
      function () {
        $(".menu").slideToggle();
        $("#responsive-menu").toggleClass("active");
      }
 );
 
});
```

```css
.main-navigation {
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 0 25px;    
}

.main-navigation a#responsive-menu {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 32px;
    float: right;
}

.main-navigation a#responsive-menu:hover,
.main-navigation a#responsive-menu:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main-navigation a#responsive-menu i {
    display: none;
}

    .main-navigation a#responsive-menu i:first-child {
        display: inline;
    }

    .main-navigation a#responsive-menu.active i:first-child {
        display: none;
    }

    .main-navigation a#responsive-menu.active i {
        display: inline;
    }

.menu {
    /*display: none;*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-navigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    .main-navigation ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 45px;
        line-height: 45px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #0091ea;
    }

        .main-navigation ul li a {
            display: inline-block;
            font-family: 'Alright_bold';
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #000;
            width: 100%;
            height: 45px;
            line-height: 45px;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 3px;
        }

        .main-navigation ul li a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .main-navigation ul li a:before {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 3px;
            width: 0;
            transition: width 0s ease, background .5s ease;
        }

        .main-navigation ul li a:after {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 3px;
            width: 0;
            background: #fff;
            transition: width .5s ease;
        }

        .main-navigation ul li a:hover:before {
            width: 100%;
            background: #fff;
            transition: width .5s ease;
        }

        .main-navigation ul li a:hover:after {
            width: 100%;
            background: transparent;
            transition: all 0s ease;
        }
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation clearfix" role="navigation">
            <a href="#" id="responsive-menu" class="visible-xs"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>

            <div class="menu" style="display:none;">
                       <ul>
                           <li class="page_item page-item-9"><a href="http://dev.monkeyapps.nl/contact/">Contact</a></li>
                           <li class="page_item page-item-5"><a href="http://dev.monkeyapps.nl/features/">Features</a></li>
                           <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://dev.monkeyapps.nl/voorbeeld-pagina/">Over MonkeyApps</a></li>
                           <li class="page_item page-item-7"><a href="http://dev.monkeyapps.nl/prijzen/">Prijzen</a></li>
                      </ul>
            </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any absolute positioned element will get the left/top position from the body not within the block it's been contained. So if you want it to be contained in the parent element then parent should be relatively positioned and then if child is absolutely positioned then left/top position will be calculated within the parent container.

Try applying the `z-index` to the `.menu`:

```
.menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:1; // number as needed
}
```

and if you want to contain it within the parent `nav` element then you can use `position:relative;` to `nav` element:

```
.main-navigation {
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 0 25px;  
    position:relative;  
}
```

---

### Updates:

You have used an alpha version of jquery 3.0 which is still in development i guess. you should use either 2.x or 1.x versions of jquery which is production ready and can be downloaded from jquery.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't seem to be the problem :(

Comment: @aardnoot then what exactly is the issue? you can ask clearly to get an answer.

Comment: Check out my JSFiddle ;)

Comment: Oh! You have used an alpha version of jquery 3.0. which is in development i guess. you should use either 2.x or 1.x.

Comment: That's indeed what problem seemed to be. Changed the version to 2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

When you use javascript to change style, javascript puts the style inline, and remove the style inline, but the styles defined in CSS sheets are still there and active. So when it toggle, it removes the style inline, but there will still be display: none in the CSS. Hence not showing the menu.

Remove `display: none;` from the CSS and add it inline, so that it doesn't show up at page load :

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ph46ecz/1/)

```
.menu {
    /*display: none;*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and in HTML :

```
<div class="menu" style="display:none;">
```